# Java, Intellij : Replacing numeric overflow expression with one which doesn't overflow

Tags: java

I have a scheduled job running, where I want to calculate time till last 30 days. For that I am getting a warning that numeric overflow detected in expression. How can I safely give 30 days?

```
@Override
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 5 5 * * ?")
    public void deleteRepliesAutomatically() {
        if(schedulerActive.equals("true")) {
            Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
// Below line gives warning. 
            long nowMinus1Week = now - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
            Timestamp nowMinus1WeekAsTimeStamp = new Timestamp(nowMinus1Week);
            Query query = session.createQuery("from Replies as cm where cm.sortTimeStamp <:limit");
            query.setParameter("limit", nowMinus1WeekAsTimeStamp);
            List<Replies> repliesList = query.list();
            for (Replies replies : repliesList) {
                session.delete(replies);
                session.flush();
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer of piet.t is in correct to fix the issue at hand.

But it would be better maintanable to use TimeUnit enum to calculate from one unit to another.
For example to have milliseconds of one week:

```
long millis = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(7);
```

You can also do a import static for DAYS.

Comment: Can I add 30 instead of 7?

Comment: @WeareBorg You can add whatever number of days you want. You can also use HOURS instead of DAYS. Or instead of toMillis you can use toSeconds() depends on your needs.

Comment: I used this one, seems more elegant.. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is your expression `(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30)`  (resulting in 2.592.000.000) is a pure `int`-computation that is overflowing (`Integer.MAX_VALUE` is 2.147.483.647).

Just make e.g. the first number a `long` by adding a `L`:

```
(1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30)
```

This will make the whole computation using the `long` datatype that is large enough to hold the value.